# No JREs that are compatible with JavaSE-16

Tags: java, environment, buildpath

The error below frequently occurs whenever a new Java Project is created. I know how to fix this issue but is there a more permanent solution so that my JDK system library is pre-installed instead of the one provided? Both eclipse and the JDK are installed but do they have to be in the same folder?

"Build path specifies execution environment JavaSE-16. No JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment."

Before:
[image: JRE Installed]

After:[image: JDK Installed]

I have tried to move my JDK into the system environment variables and have tried to re-install eclipse. I expected a prompt for the build path so that I can manually insert it but that did not occur.

[image: Installation]

Comment: It says **strictly** compatible; i.e., actually a Java 16 JDK. That said... why Java 16? Java 17 is the LTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open Eclipse and select Window->Preferences the preferences window will open.

There you can select Java, and then the sub menu Installed JREs".

There you can add a new jre/jdk to eclipse.

Ps: This will just tell Eclipse about an existing jdk. If you have not installed JDK version 16, you will have to download it from Oracle first.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I also figured out that you can select the default JRE when creating the java project. Do you have any way to do the same for JUNIT. As in, when creating a java project, it has JUNIT already in the ClassPath?

Comment: @Abdullah, if you like the answer, please mark it as the correct one